# How to let the user only edit their details and no one elses

Tags: php, sql, database

I recently created a very basic site where a user logs in and then has access to a table that they can edit. I want the user to be able to only edit their own details and no one elses, and I have no idea what I should add to the code to be able to do that. [Here is what the edit page looks like atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/astdv.png) (I'm aware it isn't very secure to show password like that, it's just an example)

Update:
I don't know what value i'm supposed to add to the delete page so it only deletes the details of logged in user and doesn't delete anyone else's. At the moment it doesn't delete any details.
This is my register page

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "pconfig.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: plogin.php");
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="plogin.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is my login page

```html
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: allcontacts.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "pconfig.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: allcontacts.php");
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="pregister.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This my contact page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Display Contacts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Display all records from Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Users</h2>

<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr.No.</td>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>

<?php

include "pconfig.php"; // Using database connection file here

$records = mysqli_query($link,"select * from users"); // fetch data from database

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['password']; ?></td>    
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr> 
<?php
}
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and finally my delete page

```html
<?php

include "pconfig.php"; // Using database connection file here



$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string
if($param_username == "$id") {
   $del = mysqli_query($link,"delete from users where id = '$id'"); // delete query
mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
    header("location:allcontacts.php"); // redirects to all records page
    exit;
}
else
{
 echo "Error deleting record"; // display error message if not delete
}

?>
```

Comment: Do not allow the user to access the database. Instead request the data for the user and then save the data for the user after sanitizing.

Comment: Please post the code you have related to login  (login form and related php / mysql code)

Comment: @KenLee just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to begin would be, when generating each (HTML) row for this table, do not echo/output an 'Edit'/'Delete' link unless the current user's UserId is equal to the row's UserId.  Also, whatever happens when the 'Edit'/'Delete' link is clicked should only run if the record's UserId is identical to the current user's UserId.

Another thought, when originally loading the (HTML) table to view the records, only query the db for the rows that are related to the current user.  Then you won't have to do any further checking before including the 'Edit'/'Delete' links.

UPDATED:
Some additional thoughts.

Do not name your database columns "id".  That's too ambiguous.  It needs to be more explicit, so that when you join multiple tables and refer to their "id" columns, you're not juggling multiple references to different "id"s.

In the "Contacts" page, include this code at the top, too.

```
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true)
{
    $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
}
else
{
    $userId = null;
}
```

Then, for the last two cells of the Contacts table, rewrite them to check the id of the user before echoing an edit or delete link.

```
<!-- BEFORE -->
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>

<!-- AFTER -->
<?php if($userId && $userId == $data['id]) { ?>
    <td>
        <a href="edit.php?id=<?=$data['id'];?>">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="delete.php?id=<?=$data['id'];?>">Delete</a>
    </td>

<?php } else { ?>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<?php } ?>
```

This will only allow a user to edit/delete his/her own contact record.

BUT!  You really need to verify these actions inside the 'edit.php' and 'delete.php' script files as well!  If a hacker knew that s/he could delete a contact simply by calling a php script file and provided an 'id' parameter in the GET request, that would make it very easy for him/her to F with your data.

Good luck!

Comment: i updated m question

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a table such as "user" which will have user details. Now when your user successfully login, you have to generate and cookie or session depending on the application that securely store the user ID. then when user wants to changes the details check whether the ID matches. furthermore, only show logged in user information in the fontend.

### Login (table)

- ID <- unique id for each user
- email
- password

### user (table)

- ID <- check whether id is same
- name
- address